# 1's complement of a number using logic gates

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, logic-gates

If I want to code a signed number into 2's complement I should use a XOR gate like this:
(Consider that A is an 8-bit input)

[image]

But if I want to code it in 1's complement how should I implement it in a logic circuit?

[image]

Comment: That xor gate won't give you the two's complement.

Comment: Could have done that with an inverter.  Then to get 2s complement, add one LSB to the result.

Answer (score 9):

Just invert all the bits. That's all 1's complement is.

In fact the circuit you show, assuming you replicated it for each bit, gives you the 1's complement. An XOR gate with an input tied high is basically just an inverter.

Comment: If I want to add/ subtract 2 signed numbers using 1's complement no matter how many bits there are, I should put as a carry-in a 1 to subtract and put an inverter for B (the second number that should be subtracted from the first number which is A). But if I want to add these numbers I should put as carry-in a 0 and then the number B will be converted to 1's complement which we don't want. So what should I do?

Comment: @PeterMurr change the second input of the XOR gates from a hard coded 1 to be controlled by the subtract/!add signal. XORing with 1 does 1s complement, XORing with 0 leaves the signal unchanged.

Comment: So I edited my post and added a new photo which I am guessing is how the adder will be and will put 1 in place of 0 if we want to subtract

Comment: @PeterMurr Looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

For what you appear to be doing (a 4 bit Adder/Subtractor)you have the circuit correct.  Your XOR gates with the S line is known as a selective compliment (i.e. it takes the one's complement if S = 1 otherwise no change is S = 0).  Since subtraction is just addition of the Two's Complement all that is left would be to add one to this, which you do by using a Full Adder for bit 0 rather than a Half Adder, and you have as the Carry input to the Full Adder, S.  So when S = 1, you take the One's Complement and you add one more to the result which is proper 2's complement arithmetic.